# Calling a USSD number or opening Phone app

Tags: ios, swift

How can I call a USSD number directly from my app, as from my research I can't use `openURL` with this url `tel://*2342#*"` because Apple prevent that

So I thought maybe I can copy the number an inform the user and then I will open the Phone app so he can paste the number, but couldn't find how to open Phone app also

Answer (score 0):

```
func dial(phoneNum: String) {

guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNum)") else {
    print("invalid url")
    return
}
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
}

}
```

The above code will open the Phone app. You should eventually pass a fake string.

Note:
 This code does NOT WORK on a simulator.